# Strip symbols/punctuation from a given string

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to remove all forms of punctuation in a string/file.

This is my code thus far.

```
>>def remove_symbols(p):
   >>punc=set('''`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|]}[{;:'",<.>/?''')
   >>for line in p:
       >>clean =''.join(c for c in line if not c in punc)
       >>print(clean)
```

But the end result looks like this if p = "I'm your's!"

I

m

y

o

u

r

s

When really, I want it to look like this --> "Im yours"

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to remove symbols from a paragraph by iterating through it one line at a time. But instead of iterating through each line, you're iterating through each character. To iterate through each line instead, use `split`:

```
def remove_symbols(p):
    punc=set('''`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|]}[{;:'",<.>/?''')
    for line in p.split("\n"):
        clean =''.join(c for c in line if not c in punc)
        print(clean)

remove_symbols("I'm your's!")
```

Result:

```
Im yours
```

Alternatively, get rid of the `for` loop entirely, and let your expression run over the whole text at once.

```
def remove_symbols(p):
    punc=set('''`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|]}[{;:'",<.>/?''')
    return ''.join(c for c in p if not c in punc)

print remove_symbols("I'm your's!")
```

Comment: Or, just: `return p.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, punc)))` :)